# Is there a function or equation that can trace the trajectory of a space rocket's motion on the three coordinate axes (x ,y ,z)?

Tags: trace

To be honest I'm working on a project at the university which is a simulation of launching a rocket into space
The problem here is that this simulation needs to be realistic enough for my programming skills
It is difficult to predict the trajectory of the missile’s movement by measuring the physical forces affecting it and applying them programmatically. Therefore, could there be an equation that tracks the rocket's movement, just as there are functions that follow the movement of the rockets?
I looked in the resources available to me and didn't find anything

Comment: You need to specify a lot more parameters for this question to have a definite answer. For example, do you take air resistance into consideration? What orbit are you launching this rocket into? What kind of thrust is applied?

Comment: ok thanks 
but the problem is that the user have the ability to control of all of this parameters